How to make a global font-switching command with \newfontfamily?
Consider the following example.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
% \begingroup %% !! Uncommenting fails !!
\newfontfamily\charis{CharisSIL}% ctan.org/pkg/charissil
% \endgroup   %% !! Uncommenting fails !!

\begin{document}
{\charis pqrs}abcd
\end{document}

The abcd has to be printed in the default font, so the output is as expected. I understand that the switch command (i.e., \charis) has to work locally, but is there any way I can declare the switch from a group? I even tried \xdefing on \charis to get a global macro, but it failed, I am guessing that it is an expansion issue. Is there any way left that I missed?

what output do you want? your code seems a bit confused and I'm not sure what you are actually trying to do. you say the output is what you expect. is it the output you want? if so, what's the problem? if not, what do you want instead?

or could you explain the use case? this feels as if it could just be an xy-problem ...

@cfr as mentioned in the question, the problem starts when I group the declaration \newfontfamily. I need to declare it in a group, but make it accessible globally. Apparently it is difficult.

What fo you mean by a global macro? Do you want to define the macro in a group and have that definition global?  That would be possible in theory but tricky as a font definition involves several connected macros, as the definition is almost alwaysv in the preamble not in a group, this isn't needed. If you mean the actual font switches global tex does not support that all font switches are local at the primitive level

@DavidCarlisle yeah, I wanted global font switches, but sad that they are unsupported. Is there any reason for this though? At least from my current use-case, I know that it's not an illogical requirement. Just curious.

presumably Knuth just thought no one would want it (and I have never seen anyone ask for that in 40 years of tex use, so he's probably not completey wrong:-)

@DavidCarlisle ouch, sounds like "people finding things after 40 years will be left unattended" :P

I'm still not clear what you mean by 'global font switch'. do you want that \charis changes the font for abcd, too? or do you want that \charis affects only pqrs, but that it is defined there despite being defined within a group? and it would be helpful if you could explain why you need this as people may have alternative suggestions, if what you want isn't supported.

@cfr in this comment I will try and clarify what I am aiming at. Suppose I do this \begingroup\gdef\abcd{abcd}\endgroup, \abcd is still accessible everywhere, right? Even outside the group. The issue is that if I, for example, define \begingroup\newfontfamily\abcd{CharisSIL}\endgroup, \abcd is inaccessible outside this group. This is what I show with the comments in my MWE that if I uncomment the lines that group the font setting command, it fails, but now I feel that was not the most efficient way of communicating. Sorry for the confusion. Hope this clarifies my problem.

When I say the output is expected, what I mean is when I type {\charis pqrs} abcd, abcd is printed in default font which is expected and is fine, but I was wondering if there was a way to define \newfontfamily "globally" (like \gdef) so that even from inside a group I can set fonts.

Now, why do I need this? Actually the use-case is a little complicated. I set certain attributes which are not supposed to "leak". So suppose I say \def\setfoofont#1{\begingroup\def\myattribute{foo}\fontsettercommand{#1}\endgroup when \fontsettercommand is defined as \expandafter\newfontfamily\csname font@\myattribute\endcsname{#1}. Ultimately I want \font@foo to be "globally" active, but the definition should be in groups. Why? Because I may need a \setbarfont also where the value of \myattribute is bar. They should have varying values locally and should be undefined elsewhere.

@DavidCarlisle just pinging you to grab your attention at my requirement. I am still curious if "theoretically" if this is an illogical requirement.

Because there is no way to do it otherwise, I have taken the risk and let \myattribute leak. Anyways the code I am writing renews \myattribute everytime with macros like \setfoofont, \setbarfont. So technically everything "just works" fine, but am I happy and worry-free? Not really :P

logically I think you should split setting up your top level user interface commands (whcih can follow normal tex grouping) with declaring the font (which is really a back end command that does not respect groups at all, the font needs to be embedded (just once) into the pdf structure as a global resource)  so even if syntactically latex would allow font dclarations within a group, it would have to manage making parts of it global  in the back end somewhere so if you end the group and then do it again you don't embed the font twice.

@DavidCarlisle thanks, this makes much more sense. I will keep this in mind.
